# Installing python-poppler-qt4 on Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: ubuntu-18.04, poppler

I am attempting to build the tool from this repo: https://github.com/taurus-forever/diffpdf-console

It requires the headerfile poppler-qt4.h to run its Makefile, which is supposedly included in some poppler dependency. The problem here is that I've installed every poppler dep I can think of from apt-get, and still can't find it. The dep "python-poppler-qt4" seems to be what I'm looking for, but I cannot locate the package on Ubuntu 18.04.

Google isn't helping. Does anyone know how to install the dep for poppler-qt4 on Ubuntu 18.04?

Comment: 1. Can you post the specific error stack trace  
2. Have you tried using pip?

Comment: Looks better. I tried "pip3 install python-poppler-qt4", got an error about sipdistutils.py missing, so I followed https://github.com/frescobaldi/python-poppler-qt5/issues/14 and manually placed it in site-packages. However, now I'm getting the error ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'sipconfig'

Answer (score 1):

just tried with
`apt-file find poppler-qt4.h`

and it says

```
emscripten: /usr/share/emscripten/tests/poppler/qt4/src/poppler-qt4.h
```

so 
`sudo apt install emscripten`
should do it

Comment: installed cleanly but still giving the "poppler-qt4.h: No such file or directory" error